# Date Popup module - I want a Time Popup as well

Tags: jquery, datetime, drupal, date, popup

I've got a field in a form (custom content type built using CCK) configured as a date and time. I have the Date Popup module installed.

My field shows up as *two* fields, one for the date and one for the time.

When users click in the date field, the JQuery calendar pops up and all is fine. But nothing happens when they click in the time field, and there are no time fields to work with in the popup.

How can I get a time popup, or otherwise assist users in choosing a time when they're filling out this field?

The Date Popup module describes itself as "Enables jquery popup calendars and time entry widgets for selecting dates and times" so it should be possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Date Popup module describes itself as "Enables jquery popup calendars and time entry widgets for selecting dates and times" so it should be possible...

First of, “time entry widgets” is not the same as a popup. There isn't a popup for the time selection and there is a good reason for that. The same reason that there is one for date selection actually: **Usability**. It will actually be more difficult and time consuming to use a popup to select time, as there are so many possibilities and it's so easy to enter and the same format is used in the world. Instead what date module uses is a special autocomplete widget, that enters the : for the user and allow them to switch between hours and minutes using the arrows. Also It does calculation for the user, so if it's only allowed to enter either 00, 15, 30, or 45 in the minutes and you then would enter the time 12:55, that would be changed to 13:00 instead, rounding up. So my guess is that everything is actually working just fine, you just didn't realize that this is how it was designed.

Comment: Hah! I kind of feel silly now because all I ever did was click in the field and nothing happened ... now I see that there is, as you say, a widget in effect, but it only takes effect when you start putting in times.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like [timepickr](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/) for jQuery.